# Showing $Cor(X,Y) = 1$ if $a>0$ and $-1$ if $a<0$

Tags: statistics, correlation

Suppose X and Y are random variables such that $Y=aX+b$ and $a$ and $b$ are constants. Show that $Cor(X,Y) = \begin{cases} +1 &\mbox{if } a > 0 \\
-1 & \mbox{if } a < 0. \end{cases}$

For this, I am using the formula for correlation provided in my book:

$$Cor(X,Y) = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}
= \frac{E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)}{\sqrt{(E(X^2) - E(X)^2)(E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2)}}$$.

I substitute in the values of X and Y=aX+b to get:

$$Cor(X,aX+b) = \frac{E(X(aX+b)) - E(X)E(aX+b)}{\sqrt{(E(X^2) - E(X)^2)(E((aX+b)^2) - E(aX+b)^2)}}$$

I know that I can pull out constants and use the sum rule, but using those just gets really messy and I don't think leads anywhere.

I know how to show this would be between -1 and 1, but I must show it is exactly -1 OR exactly 1. I assume that this would involve squaring this value, but I am lost with where to go from here. Anything I do just makes the equation monstrous. I have been told this is an "easy" proof.

Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: You might make progress by using Cov(X,Y)=E[(X-EX)(Y-EY)] and Var(rX)=r^2Var(X).

Comment: What is $r$ in the variance?

Comment: r is just some constant, $a$ is often used but that's taken here.

Comment: I've substituted the values you gave: $\frac{E[(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))]}{\sqrt{a^2Var(X)Var(X+b)}}$. I am assuming next I need to square this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the first part of your $Cor(X, Y)$ expression:
$$
Cor(X, Y)=\frac{Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}
$$
and replace $Y$ by $Y=aX+b$. Use the rules for covariances and variances to simplify.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying that now, though I think I might have done something wrong. I get $\frac{a Cov(X, X+b)}{\sqrt{a^2 Var(X)Var(X+b)}}$

Comment: Almost. $Cov(X, aX+b)=Cov(X, aX)+ Cov(X, b)=aCov(X, X)+Cov(X,b)$. Do you know what the covariance of $X$ with itself is? And what is the covariance of $X$ with a constant ($b$)? Similarly, do you know how to simplify $Var(X+b)$?

Comment: I am assuming Cov(X,X)=1? Since it depends on...itself? And Cov(X,b) =0. I am not sure how to simplify Var(X+b)

Comment: $Cov(X, X)=V(X)$, which you can see if you use the definition: $Cov(X, X)=E(XX)-E(X)E(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2=V(X)$. You also have that $Var(X + b)=Var(X)+Var(b)+2Cov(X, b)$. Since $b$ is a constant, $Var(b)=0$ (it doesn't vary). The covariance is 0 as you said, so $Var(X+b)=V(X)$. Putting all of this together, what do you get?

Comment: You actually get: $\frac{a Var(X)}{\sqrt{a^2}Var(X)}=\frac{a}{|a|}$. You are missing $Var(X)$ in the numerator (which comes from the $Cov(X, X)$ term) and in the denominator you have the square root of $Var(X)Var(X)$, i.e. $\sqrt{Var(X)^2}=Var(X)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. The 2Cov(X,b) from the translation of Var(X+b) goes to 0 and is eliminated in the denominator. This makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

$$
Cor(X,aX+b) = \frac{E(X(aX+b)) - E(X)E(aX+b)}{\sqrt{(E(X^2) - E(X)^2)(E((aX+b)^2) - E(aX+b)^2)}}
$$

let $\mu = E(X) and \sigma^2 = E(X^2), 
then

$$
E(X(aX+b)) - E(X)E(aX+b) = E(aX^2+bX) - E(X)(aE(X) + b) = aE(X^2) + bE(X) - a(E^2(X)) - bE(X) = a(E(X^2) - aE^2(X)
$$

$$
(E(X^2) - E(X)^2)(E((aX+b)^2) - E(aX+b)^2) = (\sigma^2 - \mu^2)(E(a^2X^2+2abX+b^2) - (aE(X) + b)^2 = (\sigma^2 - \mu^2)((a^2\sigma^2 +2ab\mu + b^2) - (a^2\mu^2 +2ab\mu + b^2)) = (\sigma^2 - \mu^2)(a^2(\sigma^2 - \mu^2)) = (a((\sigma^2 - \mu^2))^2
$$

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I am new here. It would help me for future answers.